# Method on package level

Tags: java, package

Is it possible to write a method that is available at package-level? Assume `foo` is a package:

```
long version = foo.getPackageVersion();
```

Comment: Nope, since packages are neither classes nor objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not. Methods can only be defined on classes. Nowhere else.

A package is not *physical*, it can't serve as a container for byte code. Packages are nothing but namespaces for classes, enums and interfaces.

Comment: You can add annotations to packages and they can provide a package version (See my answer)

Answer (score 6):

You can notionally do this in scala, but it creates a class to store these package level methods and objects.

You can create package level javadocs, and add annotations to it, but not fields, constructors or methods.

In a file called `package-info.java` in package `mypackage`

```
/**
 * Javadoc comments for package {@code mypackage}.
 */
@PackageVersion(getPackageVersion = "1.2.3")
package mypackage;
```

---

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PackageVersion {
    String getPackageVersion();
}
```

---

```
Package mypackage = Package.getPackage("mypackage");
PackageVersion version = mypackage.getAnnotation(PackageVersion.class);
System.out.println("Package version: "+version.getPackageVersion());
```

prints

```
Package version: 1.2.3
```

This facility was added in [JSR-175](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=175)

Comment: Excellent answer, this is also the direction I would take.

Answer (score 0):

No. Packages can be neither objects or classes themselves. Only classes have methods.

Answer (score 0):

In Java Methods/Operations should be inside class. Compiler complains if you try to add a method outside the class.